# Qt - how to save my QTableView as a Excel File?

Tags: excel, qt, qtableview, qt4.7, qpushbutton

Can anyone plz help me, how to save my **QtableView** as a Excel File. I have a **QTableView** and  **a QPushButton** (Save Button). If i enter the values in my QtableView and if i **click the Save Buttton the QTableView items should be saved as Excel File.** Plz Help me. Thanks..

Comment: What have you tried? Have you researched Excel file formats and decided which one to use?

Comment: Sorry am New to Qt. So am bit confused which is the best to use. can u plz suggest me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this thread [My-approach-to-export-QTableView-data-to-a-Microsoft-Excel-file](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/28345-My-approach-to-export-QTableView-data-to-a-Microsoft-Excel-file). I got this link by asking Google for: QTableView save. For the solution there you need a Qt with ODBC enabled which is not the default.

You can also study the fine documentation that contains e.g. an Address Book Example that includes a writeToFile function. You can start from there and search e.g. for information about the CSV format.

Answer (score 2):

this link worked for me :
http://www.qtcn.org/bbs/simple/?t47265.html

1-you should also use below code in .pro file. 
`QT += sql`

2-you should use `#include "exportexcelobject.h"` in your file that wanna export to excel.

Answer (score 1):

See the code sample:

ExcelExportHelper.h

```
#ifndef EXCELHELPER_H
#define EXCELHELPER_H

#include <ActiveQt/qaxobject.h>
#include <ActiveQt/qaxbase.h>
#include <QString>

//Expected in .pro file: QT += axcontainer
//Application must be of UI type for ActiveX work.
class ExcelExportHelper
{
public:
    ExcelExportHelper(const ExcelExportHelper& other) = delete;
    ExcelExportHelper& operator=(const ExcelExportHelper& other) = delete;

    ExcelExportHelper(bool closeExcelOnExit = false);
    void SetCellValue(int lineIndex, int columnIndex, const QString& value);
    void SaveAs(const QString& fileName);

    ~ExcelExportHelper();

private:
    QAxObject* m_excelApplication;
    QAxObject* m_workbooks;
    QAxObject* m_workbook;
    QAxObject* m_sheets;
    QAxObject* m_sheet;
    bool m_closeExcelOnExit;
};

#endif // EXCELHELPER_H
```

ExcelExportHelper.cpp

```
#include <ActiveQt/qaxobject.h>
#include <ActiveQt/qaxbase.h>

#include <QString>
#include <QFile>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

#include "ExcelExportHelper.h"

ExcelExportHelper::ExcelExportHelper(bool closeExcelOnExit)
{
    m_closeExcelOnExit = closeExcelOnExit;
    m_excelApplication = nullptr;
    m_sheet = nullptr;
    m_sheets = nullptr;
    m_workbook = nullptr;
    m_workbooks = nullptr;
    m_excelApplication = nullptr;

    m_excelApplication = new QAxObject( "Excel.Application", 0 );//{00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}

    if (m_excelApplication == nullptr)
        throw invalid_argument("Failed to initialize interop with Excel (probably Excel is not installed)");

    m_excelApplication->dynamicCall( "SetVisible(bool)", false ); // hide excel
    m_excelApplication->setProperty( "DisplayAlerts", 0); // disable alerts

    m_workbooks = m_excelApplication->querySubObject( "Workbooks" );
    m_workbook = m_workbooks->querySubObject( "Add" );
    m_sheets = m_workbook->querySubObject( "Worksheets" );
    m_sheet = m_sheets->querySubObject( "Add" );
}

void ExcelExportHelper::SetCellValue(int lineIndex, int columnIndex, const QString& value)
{
    QAxObject *cell = m_sheet->querySubObject("Cells(int,int)", lineIndex, columnIndex);
    cell->setProperty("Value",value);
    delete cell;
}

void ExcelExportHelper::SaveAs(const QString& fileName)
{
    if (fileName == "")
        throw invalid_argument("'fileName' is empty!");
    if (fileName.contains("/"))
        throw invalid_argument("'/' character in 'fileName' is not supported by excel!");

    if (QFile::exists(fileName))
    {
        if (!QFile::remove(fileName))
        {
            throw new exception(QString("Failed to remove file '%1'").arg(fileName).toStdString().c_str());
        }
    }

    m_workbook->dynamicCall("SaveAs (const QString&)", fileName);
}

ExcelExportHelper::~ExcelExportHelper()
{
    if (m_excelApplication != nullptr)
    {
        if (!m_closeExcelOnExit)
        {
            m_excelApplication->setProperty("DisplayAlerts", 1);
            m_excelApplication->dynamicCall("SetVisible(bool)", true );
        }

        if (m_workbook != nullptr && m_closeExcelOnExit)
        {
            m_workbook->dynamicCall("Close (Boolean)", true);
            m_excelApplication->dynamicCall("Quit (void)");
        }
    }

    delete m_sheet;
    delete m_sheets;
    delete m_workbook;
    delete m_workbooks;
    delete m_excelApplication;
}
```

Usage:

```
try
{
    const QString fileName = "g:\\temp\\kaka2.xlsx";

    ExcelExportHelper helper;

    helper.SetCellValue(1,1,"Test-11");
    helper.SetCellValue(1,2,"Test-12");

    helper.SaveAs(fileName);
}
catch (const exception& e)
{
    QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error - Demo", e.what());
}
```